# div text vertical align

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div: one parent and one child. User can add this div with button click and they set the text value. I want to display these dives in border inline-block(3 items in 1 row, like new tabs in chrome). And I want to display this text in the center of border.
There is css code:

```
.parentDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.childDiv {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle to show you a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nfLu3/

```
.parentDiv {
    ...
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}

.childDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:1;
}​
```

the keys are:

- set the `line-height` of the parent container to its height (`200px`) and the `text-align` to `center`. So some text appears exactly in the middle of your box.
- set the child container to be `display` as `inline-block`. In this way it's oriented at the text around (it's important!). The text around (I mean the line breaks and spaces before the child container) has a `line-height` of `200px` and the child block has `vertical-align:middle`, so it will be centered.

there you go

Comment: It's good but in Chrome it doesn't work. What I must add that it will work in Chrome? I'm just beginner and don't know.

Comment: well, I tested it with chrome, works perfect (see the fiddle above)